# mysql 1300 Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x8C' with Unicode emoji

Tags: python, mysql, emoji, pymysql, utf8mb4

So I'm trying to commit unicode emoji to database (this one especially:)
But everytime something with emoji is executed on database this happens:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1300, "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x8C'")
```

I've read a little bit on this topic, and found out I should change charset to utf8mb4 to make unicode emojis work, so now my connection looks like this:

```
mydb = mysql.connect(host=os.getenv("db_host", "localhost"),
                                          user=os.getenv("db_username", "Mashu"),
                                          password=os.getenv("db_password"),
                                          port=self._tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                          db=os.getenv("database"),
                                          charset='utf8mb4')
```

But it still refuses to work, I have no idea what to do now...

Whole code:

```
mydb = mysql.connect(host=os.getenv("db_host", "localhost"),
                                          user=os.getenv("db_username", "Mashu"),
                                          password=os.getenv("db_password"),
                                          port=self._tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                          db=os.getenv("database"),
                                          charset='utf8mb4')

payload = Payload()
payload.id: int
payload.message_id: int
payload.channel_id: int
payload.emoji = ""

def foo(payload)
cursor = self.bot.mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    f"SELECT role FROM RR_Roles INNER JOIN RR_Panels ON RR_Roles.panel_id = 
    payload.id WHERE emoji = '{emoji}' AND guild = '{payload.channel_id}' AND 
message = '{payload.message_id}'")
print(curosor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`